# Postgres query to select based on row count and existence

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This might sound involved, so please bear with me. :)

I have two tables: `users` and `profiles`. Users can have many profiles, which are filled out when the user OAuths into a provider like Facebook or Google. `profiles` has a column with the `source` name like 'Google' or 'Facebook', and a column with the profile's public `image_url`.

If a user has an associated profile, I want to use `image_url` in an `img` tag when I display the user in a list on a webpage. If the user has multiple profiles, I want to prefer the Facebook image over Google.

So for all users, I want to get the proper `image_url` along with the other `user.*` attributes. Can I do this entirely in one Postgres query? If so, what would it look like?

So far (embarrassingly), all I have is this:

```
select image_url from users join profiles on users.id = profiles.user_id;
```

This will give me multiple rows if a user has connected more than one profile. I'd like to modify this query so that:

- Users without an associated profile should have `null` for the `image_url`
- Users who only have an associated Google profile should have the image URL from that Google profile
- Users who only have an associated Facebook profile should have the image URL from that Facebook profile
- Users who have both an associated Facebook profile and a Google profile should have the Facebook image URL

Can any SQL experts weigh in? Thanks!

Clarifications:

- Profiles can only be from Facebook or Google. A user can only have 1 Facebook profile and/or 1 Google profile. (That is, a user cannot have multiple Google profiles nor can he have multiple Facebook profiles.)

Comment: Can a user have multiple profiles that do not include either Facebook or Google?

Comment: @vivek, Your query will not return the Google image_url. I'll write a clarification

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. All the relevant columns are mentioned in the question including how the tables relate to one another... What do you think is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution would use two CTE's and a `COALESCE`:

```
WITH fb AS (
  SELECT user_id, image_url
  FROM profiles
  WHERE profile = 'Facebook'
), ggl AS (
  SELECT user_id, image_url
  FROM profiles
  WHERE profile = 'Google'
)
SELECT users.*, COALESCE(fb.image_url, ggl.image_url)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN ggl ON ggl.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN fb ON fb.user_id = users.id
```

The first CTE gets the Facebook image_url, if available, the second CTE gets the Google image_url. The `COALESCE` makes sure that the Facebook image_url is selected if present.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'd been trying to look into the `CASE` keyword. I wasn't aware of the `COALESCE`.

Comment: That's funny because it is the same page in the docs! Just keep reading.

Comment: I guess I was just looking at StackOverflow answers and tutorials about `CASE` haha